# Significance of Joe giving cigars to the team in Flash S04E04

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash

In Flash Season 4 Episode 3 [Elongated Journey Into Night](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Elongated_Journey_Into_Night), at the end of the episode Joe tells Flash that Cecile is pregnant.

And in next scene everyone is happy and Joe giving them Cigars.

Why is that? Is that any kind of tradition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Why is that? Is that any kind of tradition?*

Sort of. There is an old tradition, not commonly observed anymore where new fathers pass cigars out to their friends in celebration of the birth of a new child. This was primarily done with the birth of new sons, and almost always *after* the birth, not the announcement of the pregnancy.

[Reference.com explains a bit](https://www.reference.com/world-view/tradition-cigars-baby-born-3add781a6f58b1a9#).

> The tradition of handing out cigars after the birth of a baby was primarily upheld in England and the United States, including American Indians. The tradition also stemmed from the fact that fathers were generally excluded from the birth process until after the baby was born, at which point the men congregated with friends and family to celebrate by smoking cigars.

Perhaps on Earth-1, the tradition is just a little bit different than on our Earth.

Comment: Although the *tradition* is to hand them out to celebrate the birth, I have seen people hand them out "early" (e.g., at the announcement of the pregnancy).  Not quite as traditional, but not unheard of.